# How to call a JavaScript function without having to write it more than once in the HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have the following HTML lines calling a JS function.

```
<h3>
    <span class="my-class" onclick="myFunc()">one</span>
    <span class="my-class" onclick="myFunc()">two</span>
    <span class="my-class" onclick="myFunc()">three</span>
    <span class="my-class" onclick="myFunc()">four</span>
</h3>
```

How can I call `myFunc()` right from the script without having to repeat myself by writing `onclick="myFunc()"` so many times in the HTML file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: Don’t inline JS. Use `document.querySelectorAll`. Iterate through the collection. Use `Element.prototype.addEventListener('click')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use codes below :

```
var elements= document.getElementsByClassName("my-class");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunc, false);
}
```

Comment: This won't work. You have `myFunc()` when what you want is `myFunc`.  The second arg to `addEventListener()` must be of type 'function'; `myFunc()` is not of type 'function'; it's whatever type is returned by `myFunc()`.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt what I'm coming to share in a tutorial and it works for me.

```
  function myFunc()
  {
    console.log('Body of myFunc');
  }

  var span_list = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class');

  for(this_span = 0; this_span < span_list.length; this_span++)
  {
     span_list[this_span].addEventListener('click', myFunc);
  }
```

With this method, you have access to do something peculiar to a specific element by using the '**getAttribute()**' method on one of your class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This won't work. As with another answer here, you have `myFunc()` when what you want is `myFunc`.  The second arg to `addEventListener()` must be of type 'function'; `myFunc()` is not of type 'function'; it's whatever type is returned by `myFunc()`.

Comment: Yeah.. that's true.. Is a typo. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the listener to multiple elements by looping through the results of a method such as [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Furthermore, you can also reduce repitition in your markup by assigning the class once to the parent element. In this case, it would be the `<h3>` element. Then you modify your query selector accordingly.

Here's an example where I've assigned an `id` to each `<span>` element to facilitate identifying which element was clicked:

```js
function myFunc() {
  console.log(`myFunc() called for ${this.id}`);
}

for (const e of document.querySelectorAll('h3.my-class > span')) {
  e.addEventListener('click', myFunc, false);
}
```

```html
<h3 class="my-class">
  <span id="one">one</span>
  <span id="two">two</span>
  <span id="three">three</span>
  <span id="four">four</span>
</h3>
```